# What is the value of $-\log\left(\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}\right)+2\log(\pi)-\log(2)\right)$?

Tags: roots, infinity, transcendental-numbers

I'm struggling with this one. Assuming the natural log, Mathematica gives the following result:
$$-\log\left(\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}\right)+2\log(\pi)-\log(2)\right)=\infty$$
But working it out myself I see that:
$$\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}\right)+2\log(\pi)-\log(2) = 0$$
Which simplifies to:$$-\log(0)$$
Is this undefined? Is the original equation malformed?

Usually, I can make a mental picture to understand this stuff but I'm struggling here. I sense a fracturing, perhaps akin to what happens in rocks during an earthquake, or when quaternions go rogue in an otherwise decent subroutine.

Curiously, WolframAlpha gives the following transcendental result:
$$-\log\left(\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}\right)+2\log(\pi)-\log(2)\right)=50\log(2)$$

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious but I can't quite sniff it out.

Comment: While it is best to say that log(0) is undefined, looking at the graph we see that as x tends to 0, log(x) tends to negative infinity. Negative of negative infinity, is what you got through Mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica and WolframAlpha are simply incorrect here.

Comment: Look at a graph of $\log x$ (and compare it to a graph of $e^x$): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+log+x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the middle part first. Apparently $\log(\frac{2}{\pi^2})+2\log(\pi)-\log(2)=\log(2)-\log(2)=0$ from logarithmic identities.

The final result, $-\log(0)$, is undefined since $0$ is a singularity point for the logarithmic function. We may nevertheless interpret the Mathematica result as a limit, as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}-\log(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: Ah, interpreting the result as a limit helps! Thank you.

Comment: Am I correct then in imagining these points like little wavepackets--mostly benign until encountering other similar points?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. At $x=0$ it just blows up.

Comment: That is so freaking cool.

Comment: And in different bases the same behavior?

Comment: The result just differs by a constant when the base is different, due to the change-of-base formula $\log_a x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$.

Comment: I guess the pressing question becomes "what sort of maths helps to eliminate ambiguity here?" Looking at some books on Gauge theory now.

Comment: <opens pandora's box> See you in a few years, studying.

Comment: But seriously, thank you, from the most deepest place in my heart.